# Buffer is accessed out of bounds in cppcheck

Tags: c, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

Code can be compiled and result is fine.
But cppcheck will report an error of it.

```
#define BUF_SIZE     1024
#define MAX_LENG     80

static unsigned char path[MAX_LENG];
unsigned char file_buf[BUF_SIZE*2];

memset(file_buf, 0, sizeof(file_buf));
strcpy(file_buf, "KID ");
strncat(file_buf, &path[strlen(path)-12], 10); //error this line
```

I tried a few time, and still cannot find the reason.
Anyone can give me some hints ?

Thanks all the answers.

but I have more questions:
If this is a fatal error , why compiler passed and result is what I want ?
Under what condition it will have trouble ?

There is any alternative way to realize it ?

And if I changed it into

```
strncat(file_buf, &path[strlen(path)-12], 5);
```

cppcheack error will disappear. Why?

Answer (score 3):

This here buffer:

```
static unsigned char path[MAX_LENG];
```

Is static, and therefore zero initialized. The first character is 0 when this code is first executed. As such `strlen(path)` is going to return `(size_t)0`. Subtract 12 from that and you get a very large unsigned number due to modular arithmetic, a number most definitely larger than `1024`.

Answer (score 2):

You access an array with a too large index:

```
static unsigned char path[MAX_LENG];
```

Being `static` it is initialized to zeroes. This means `strlen(path)` will return 0.

```
strncat(file_buf, &path[strlen(path)-12], 10);
```

Here you subtract 12 which would be -12 but as `strlen` returns an unsigned value the resulting index is `SIZE_MAX-12` which is clearly out of bounds.

Comment: @M.M Since the number circle the actual index is -12, if `strlen` returns zero. Valid array indices are positive numbers, but it's actually an access *before* the array.

Comment: @harper no it isn't.